# Swift ambiguous reference to member '=='

Tags: swift, swift3

Is this a bug in Swift 3 compiler? It's not ambiguous, it's `==` and two `String`s.

It says:

```
error: ambiguous reference to member '=='
let strs = things.filter { return $0.id == "1" } .map { t in
                                        ^~
```

For this example code:

```
class Thing {
    var id: String = ""
}
let things = [Thing]()
let x = 1
let strs = things.filter { return $0.id == "1" } .map { t in
    if x == 1 {
        return "a"
    }
    else {
        return "b"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a misleading error message – the ambiguity actually lies with the closure expression you're passing to `map(_:)`, as Swift cannot infer the return type of a multi-line closure without any external context.

So you could make the closure a single line using the ternary conditional operator:

```
let strs = things.filter { $0.id == "1"} .map { _ in
    (x == 1) ? "a" : "b"
}
```

Or simply supply the compiler some explicit type information about what `map(_:)` is returning:

```
let strs = things.filter { $0.id == "1"} .map { _ -> String in
```

```
let strs : [String] = things.filter { $0.id == "1"} .map { _ in
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar issue where the `<` operator was marked as ambiguous when trying to use my own filter function:

```
let shortNames = names.myFilter { (name) -> Bool in
    return name.count < 4
}
```

Similarly to the answer from @Hamish I fixed this by explicitly setting the type of name:

```
(name: String)
```

I shouldn't have to do this of course but it works.